# SoftPWM library disables regular PWM?

Tags: arduino

I was working with this library: [SoftPWM Library](https://code.google.com/p/rogue-code/wiki/SoftPWMLibraryDocumentation)

but when I try to run it in parallel with regular PWM/analog write functions, I just get occasional flickering.

To check, I included SoftPWM into the standard *fade* example and just initializing the library (`SoftPWMBegin();`) interrupted the analog writing process.

Can someone, who knows more about the system behind it, explain why this is happening, or if there is a way to work around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the answer: softPWM uses the Arduino internal timer2 which is directly linked to pins 9 and 10 and makes these unavailable for pwm functions.

http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=19451.0

Answer (score 0):

SoftPWM uses Timer2, but it is linked to pins 3 and 11.
Pins 9 and 10 are controlled by 16 bits Timer1.

https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=328094.0